# Rationale for design of UITableViewDataSource

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm designing an API interface for a magazine viewer. Something like iGizmo (for iPad). The view that displays a magazine is very similar to a TableView. As one can think about articles as sections and pages as cells.

Because of that I'd like to expose DataSource & Delegate in the same manner as UITableView does. However I'm not entirely sure why apple designed TableView delegate/DataSource in that way it always provide the TableView as parameter in each method.

I've tried to rationalize it and I didn't find any good excuse for such api design.
I'm thinking about leaving out the `tableView`/`magazineView` parameter in my API.

**Do you see any good reasons behind such API design?**

**Wouldn't it be easier and clearer to write methods like the one below?**

```
– cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
– numberOfSections
– numberOfRowsInSection:
– sectionIndexTitles
– sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:
– titleForHeaderInSection:
– titleForFooterInSection:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. Whilst this is a guess, I suspect it's there so a single data source class can be the delegate for multiple table views with differing requirements. (i.e.: It can check the tableView that's provided and respond accordingly.)

As such, if you don't ever anticipate this requirement, you could most likely omit the equivalent parameter from your method signatures.

Then again, if it's at all possible that you might want to access the "calling" magazineView, you could just leave the parameter in there - it's not as if passing a pointer around is incredibly resource inefficient.

Comment: Exactly right, a data source might serve content to many views and a delegate may be the delegate of many views. Additionally in some cases a delegate or datasource might need to inspect the view calling it to determine how to respond.

Comment: @Jonah, @middaparka, I agree, but have you ever implemented a datasource that way that one instance was serving multiple tableviews? Why not creating two instances of the same  datasource class. Such API design seems to ignore the fact that objc is an OO language.

Comment: I'll write a data source to provide a specific view of some model and certainly might reuse that data source instance to back multiple views, different table views in different orientations for example, but I agree the data source usually would not need to consider the object requesting the data. My delegates on the other hand check the identity of their caller all the time, for example I might manage a collection of NSURLConnections using a single class acting as their collective delegate.

Comment: @Piotr Have to agree with Jonah, in that the most likely usage for such a set up would be to have two different views on the same data, which is a *reasonably* common occurrence.